# How to decrypt MS SQL hexadecimal file names?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hex

I have a column named content with image file names stored in hexadecimal format, I want to decrypt them and know the image file names stored. Is there any way I can do that?

[image]

Comment: You have a column that contains a blob. Do you KNOW it is encrypted or is this an assumption? My guess it is not encrypted at all and simply contains an actual image (based on the table name and the other columns). You need to know what type of image it is in order to "use" it.

Comment: I should also note that the image datatype has been deprecated for 15 years.

Comment: I'm converting the actual hex but its giving me random characters, I guess its encrpted. How to know the encryption key?

Comment: Yes I currently need to know the image type  so I can upload them to AWS accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Your question specifies file names but, with the column named `Content`, I would expect the actual value to be the raw binary file contents of the file rather than the file name. The similar hex values suggest the value is not encrypted. Add `DATALENGTH(Content)` to your query; a large size might confirm my suspicion.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes the contents are large, seems like a raw file but I can't compare this image datatype with varchar to run scripts and have tried various image type preview methods but have no luck in figuring how to view the content or know the file type

Comment: Your best bet is to find out more from the originating application. Varchar will not help you decode this binary data.

Comment: @DanGuzman the column 'Content' is of image type, for the rest of the tables when I extract the data type, it give me the format of PNG but for this specific table it gives me BIN which is unreadable by all the scripts or tools I used. Are these blobs corrupted or something?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), content, 0)
```

example :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), 0x4D616E75623232, 0)
```

Comment: Its giving me random characters like'_''''''y_', I guess its encrypted. Is there any way to know the encryption key and then decrypt it

Comment: Can't compare varchar to image datatype, this error is displayed.